# using tab inside docker container does not expand path files and directory names

Tags: bash, docker

Team,

i have docker container in which when i use tab on terminal it does not expand the listing of current directory.
any reason?

suppose you want to see /bin

```
# ls bi [hit tab here] and enter
ls: cannot access 'bi': No such file or directory
#
```

```
# uname -a
Linux f6648b3a938e 5.10.124-linuxkit #1 SMP Thu Jun 30 08:19:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

env

```
# env
HOSTNAME=f6648b3a938e
HOME=/root
OLDPWD=/code/
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/sonar-scanner/bin
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
CUE_VERSION=v0.4.2
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/
TINI_VERSION=v0.19.0
```

expectation

`ls bi[tab] >>>> ls bin`

Comment: Do you see a tab appearing when you press Ctrl+V first, or in `cat` command? If yes, then this is a problem with your shell, otherwise with docker or terminal or something else. Assuming first (as it is easier to solve), does you `.bashrc` contain something like `bind -u complete` or anything related to completion? Does this work the same with `bash --norc`?